# right align logo in tcpdf header

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf, graphical-logo

I have the following tcdpf syntax in my php document:

```
$title="My Heading";
$obj_pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.$title, PDF_HEADER_STRING, array(0,64,255), array(0,64,128));
```

The logo appears on the left, how can I right align the `logo` and left align `$title`?

Answer (score 6):

You must define custom header to align image.
This [example](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_003.phps)
 shows how to do this.

To align your logo right, you must set palign attribute to 'R' in image definition.

```
$this->Image($image_file, 10, 10, 15, '', 'JPG', '', 'T', false, 300, 'R', false, false, 0,     false, false, false);
```

Note that, your header data string position may not be what you want as. You will probably

need to play with several attributes, but in basic, image alignment can be done only via

overriding default Header() function as far as I know.

Check also [Image()](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a714c2bee7d6b39d4d6d304540c761352) function.

Comment: Thanks, how does this ties into:

`$obj_pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.$title, PDF_HEADER_STRING, array(0,64,255), array(0,64,128));`

Comment: Because you are overwriting, that line is not important know. `$this->Image(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, 10, 10, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, '', 'JPG', '', 'N', false, 300, 'R', false, false, 0, false, false, false) ` probably will set your logo as what you wanted, but you need to set your header data cell by cell in your own Header() as shown in example provided in my answer. Note that I set palign attribute of Image to 'N' which is new line because your header data may position at your logo. Check also [Cell()](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a33b265e5eb3e4d1d4fedfe29f8166f31).